# Extract Compressed file to folder and GOTO (or select) that folder?

Tags: windows, zip, 7-zip

My downloads folder is huge. That's where most downloaded zipped files go to. I right click the file and extract it to a folder within the same download directory. Windows doesn't automatically select that new folder so now I have to find it to see the extracted content. If the name's kind of unique I could type it in and the file browser would navigate to it instantly, but if not it would be a pain.

My question is, is there a way to have Windows auto-select or auto-open the folder it extracted the contents of the compressed file into? Maybe a batch script or something?

Comment: Are you extracting to the default name? You extract using 7zip?

Comment: Sort by date...it will be the first folder

Comment: Yes I just do 'extract as' and it will create a folder with the same name as the zipped file. 7Zip yes. And that's what I usually end up doing sorting by date but that's not really ideal.

Comment: I use [XYPlorer](https://www.xyplorer.com/free.php) - there is a sort option that allows directories to be sorted in amongst the files (disable "Sort Folders Apart"). Your new folder will be the next entry up from the zip file. https://i.imgur.com/0BPT1gt.png